# Solving a dp problem from codeforces - Cut Ribbon

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve [this](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/189/A) problem and from the comments section in the editorial, I was directed to the following solution :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX(a,b,c) max(a,max(b,c))

int n,a,b,c,dp[4001];

int f(int x)
{
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    if (x < 0 || (x > 0 && x < a && x < b && x < c)) 
        return 0xACCE97ED;                              // <- **I have doubt here**
    if (!dp[x]) dp[x] = MAX(f(x-a),f(x-b),f(x-c)) + 1;
        return dp[x];
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n >> a >> b >> c;
    memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
    cout << f(n) << endl;
}
```

I wanted to know:

1. What is the need of the if statement that returns `0xACCE97ED` for the test case:
   `4000 1 2 3`. This test case dosen't work when that specific `if` statement is missing.
2. Why specifically `0xACCE97ED` is being returned? Because when I tried to return any other number (say 9999), then the output is `expected output + 9999`.

Comment: Not related to your question: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: If you use c++14 or newer then you don't need to create custom functionality to get the maximum number from any amount of numbers: `std::max({f(x-a), f(x-b), f(x-c)})`.

Comment: Does checking ``x > 0 && x < a && x < b && x < c`` necessary here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```c
    if (x < 0 || (x > 0 && x < a && x < b && x < c)) 
        return 0xACCE97ED;    // -1395746835
```

Well looking at the dp function, it is basically maximizing values and this specific if statement is saying:

`if x < 0`
the length of the ribbon you cut is negative (which should be impossible)

`or if x > 0 and x < a, b, c` which means you can still cut X but all available sizes would result into having a ribbon of negative length

`return 0xACCE97ED;` return a random negative value which happens to spell out ACCEPTED because this state is invalid

And since the third if statement will try to get the max value, 0xACCE97ED will never be selected as the max value.

Comment: Then why doesn't the code work for the given test case when this if statement is missing?

Comment: the statement should not be removed because it is removing the invalid state. If you try to change the return value to -1, it will still work.

Comment: now the test case ```100 23 15 50``` is disturbing when I put return -1. The expected output is 2 and answer is 5. Could you please help me this last time ! You've been very helpful, thanks.

Comment: I tried to manually do the tree and 2 is correct. 100 > 50 > 0 = 2 ribbons.

Comment: Remember the goal is to go from 100 to 0 and 23 * 4 = 92 which means you need an 8 and 15 * 6 = 90 which means you need a 10. Any combinations of the two still wouldn't give a 100.

Comment: Does checking ``x > 0 && x < a && x < b && x < c`` necessary here?

Comment: Yes, because there should be no leftovers.

Answer (score 1):

0xACCE97ED means "ACCEPTED" in the `1ee7` speech. nothing else specific about this value.

Comment: Is 0xACCE97ED a defined constant string for C++ language? And if so, how does it solve the issue?

Comment: @TapasviBhatt it's not a defined constant. it could be anything like 0xC001BABE or whatever you like. you wanted to know why it's being returned -- I'm telling you there's nothing particular about this constant. you may use any other you like.

Comment: But the question demands some other output. In the given test-case, expected output is 4000 then, how does returning "accepted" or any other constant solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the need of the if statement that returns 0xACCE97ED for the test case: 4000 1 2 3

```
if (x < 0 || (x > 0 && x < a && x < b && x < c)) 
    return 0xACCE97ED;                              // <- **I have doubt here**
```

because the function `f` is recursive, in the next line it calls itself:

```
if (!dp[x]) dp[x] = MAX(f(x-a),f(x-b),f(x-c)) + 1;
    return dp[x];
```

with a smaller values for `x` so presumable it will eventually make that `if` statement `true` and will `return` "accepted" (`0xACCE97ED`).

Comment: This is the first time I've come across this ```0xACCE97ED```. Can you please tell me why is the output ```4000``` if the function returns "accepted" because I think the function ends when it encounters the first return statement so it must not move to the next line once it encounters : ```return 0xACCE97ED```.